# Generating Excel files with JScript

Tags: javascript, jscript, wsh

I realised that you can generate excel files using JScript/JavaScript with just a few lines of code. But then it got me wondering; why doesn't anybody ever mention this. All I see online is "Use third party components" or "You need to write a library" or links to other MS documentation that involve massive amounts of code to be written.

But why not just use WSH? It's practically perfect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using excel component on server side sometimes impossible (like if the server is linux) and also requires to buy excel license for the server. also excel my not be good for frequent use. because it can't be such fast as a component designed for that and require much more resources.

for tiny tasks for yourself it is possible to use VBA and excel. but if you intend to sell a  software the buyer might no have excel installed. but you can require the use to have excel installed for export to excel.

Comment: Thank you @Shimon that helped clear things up :)